# How to create and use a case insensitive IList<string> in Spring4d

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, spring4d

I'm trying the following code to create a case insensitive IList:

```
procedure TForm1.ListButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyList: IList<string>;
begin
  MyList := TCollections.CreateList<string>(TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase());
  MyList.AddRange(['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(MyList.IndexOf('aaa').ToString);
end;
```

However the IndexOf call always returns -1.  Should this work?  Any suggestions appreciated.

Update:  It looks like the comparer is used for sorting, but not for IndexOf.  A separate "EqualityComparer" is used for IndexOf, so the question becomes how to change it?

Update2: I just wanted to add to Johan's answer that the list can then be created like so:

```
MyCIList := TCaseInsensitiveList<string>.Create(
  TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase(),
  TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Spring4D hotfix 1.2.1.  With the change the code below works as expected.

```
procedure TForm1.ListButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyList: IList<string>;
begin
  MyList := TCollections.CreateList<string>(TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase());
  MyList.AddRange(['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(MyList.IndexOf('aaa').ToString);  // Correctly returns 0.
end;
```

Comment: Great! and I'm just in need of this feature. Couldn't find the spring4d  spring4d 1.2.1 hotfix you mentioned, but spring 1.2  dated 2017-11-03 worked.

Answer (score 1):

The code of IndexOf looks like this:

```
function TList<T>.IndexOf(const item: T; index, count: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TArray.IndexOf<T>(fItems, item, index, count, EqualityComparer);
end;
```

The EqualityComparer is a property that calls GetEqualityComparer which looks like:

```
protected
  class function GetEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>; static;
```

This `static` means the method cannot be overriden in a child class.

You need to edit the source of Spring and make the following change:

**Spring.Collections.Base**

```
103:   TEnumerableBase<T> = class abstract(TEnumerableBase, IEnumerable<T>)
106:   protected
108:   class var fEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>;  
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//Move this line from private to the protected section.
.......

                                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Now you can create your own `TCaseInsensitiveList` like so:

```
type
  TCaseInsensitiveList<T> = class(Spring.Collections.TList<T>)
    constructor Create(const Comparer: IComparer<T>; 
                       const EqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>);
  end;
  .....
constructor TCaseInsensitiveList<T>.Create(
             const Comparer: IComparer<T>; 
             const EqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>);
begin
  inherited Create(Comparer);
  Self.fEqualityComparer:= EqualityComparer;
end;
```

Or alternatively you can declare the base `GetEqualityComparer` class function to be virtual and override that in a child class.

There is a cost to making the `GetEqualityComparer` virtual, which is why I choose to make the underlying class variable protected.

Comment: Very nice!  Small note that the class( part should be class(Spring.Collections.Lists.TList<T>).  I see that you created an issue mentioning this in the Spring4D issue tracker... Thank you!